# Using canvas element inside ion-grid

Tags: ionic-framework, canvas

The following code does not work:

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row no-wrap align-items-start>
        <ion-col>
          <div>
            <canvas id="chart-1"></canvas>
          </div>                  
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <div>
            <canvas id="chart-2"></canvas>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

As far as I can tell, this is page one of the ionic API on using the grid, and I can't make any sense of it. It works fine if I use img tags. I've just bunged three identical images in and they work fine. But canvas does not work...

[screen shot of it not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvZbE.png)

Any clues?

Comment: Are you doing anything with your canvas? It's blank to begin with.

Comment: Yes. I'm filling them with charts using chart.js. If the screen shot link works, it shows a couple of guage charts. Plus a few simple images that I dropped in, just to prove that I wasn't going mad. And they work as expected, with the same ion-row , ion-col structure, just with 3.